# Macro for automatic generation serialization function for a class

Tags: c++, boost, macros

I often describing the existing structures, and I need whatever method to automatically generate structure map...

As example, I have small structure:

```
struct SExampleBox
{
  int   x;    //0x0000
  int   y;    //0x0004
  float size; //0x0008

}; Size=0x000C
```

My idea is to describe it as: (using macro or maybe boost.preprocessor)

```
STRUCT_BEGIN(SExampleBox)
  MEMBER(int, x);
  MEMBER(int, y);
  MEMBER(float size);
STRUCT_END
```

To expand it automatically to:

```
struct SExampleBox
{
  int x;
  int y;
  float size;
};

void DUMP__SExampleBox(SExampleBox *obj)
{
  printf("%p > SExampleObj:\n", obj);
  printf("  0x%04x - int x = %d\n", offsetof(SExampleObj, x), obj->x);
  printf("  0x%04x - int y = %d\n", offsetof(SExampleObj, y), obj->y);
  printf("  0x%04x - float size = %f\n", offsetof(SExampleObj, size), obj->size);
}
```

To call DUMP__SExampleBox(test); and get an example output:

```
0x00402000 > SExampleObj:
  0x0000 - int x = 100
  0x0004 - int y = 50
  0x0008 - float size = 200.000f
```

Is there's any possible way to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: I can do a simple macro for 

#define STRUCT_BEGIN(a) struct a {
#define MEMBER_INT(n) int n;
#define MEMBER_FLOAT(n) float n;
#define STRUCT_END };

But I don't know how to generate a separate function for serialization (DUMP__SExampleBox)...

Comment: Using double underscores is reserved for standard library. That's undefined behaviour

Comment: are you opposed to adding a small text processor that builds those struct and functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite satisfied with the value formatting juggle, but that's tweakable.

The syntax looks like this:

```
DECLARE_STRUCT(SExampleBox,
    (int, x)
    (int, y)
    (float, size)
)

int main(int, char**) {
    SExampleBox o{1, 2, 3.14f};
    dump(&o);
}
```

Now, the implementation. First, we'll need a utility function to add parentheses to a Boost.PP sequence, turning `(a)(b)` into `((a))((b))`:

```
#define glk_pp_detail_doubleSeqParens_0(...)\
     ((__VA_ARGS__)) glk_pp_detail_doubleSeqParens_1

#define glk_pp_detail_doubleSeqParens_1(...)\
     ((__VA_ARGS__)) glk_pp_detail_doubleSeqParens_0

#define glk_pp_detail_doubleSeqParens_0_end
#define glk_pp_detail_doubleSeqParens_1_end

#define glk_pp_doubleSeqParens(seq)\
    BOOST_PP_CAT(glk_pp_detail_doubleSeqParens_0 seq, _end)
```

Then we'll build the skeleton of the struct declaration and the corresponding function:

```
#define DECLARE_STRUCT(name_, fields_) \
    struct name_ { \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DETAIL_DECLARE_FIELD, name_, glk_pp_doubleSeqParens(fields_)) \
    }; \
    void dump(name_ *obj_) { \
        ::std::printf("%p > " BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(name_) ":\n", static_cast<void*>(obj_)); \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DETAIL_PRINT_FIELD, name_, glk_pp_doubleSeqParens(fields_)) \
    }
```

The double-parentheses from `glk_pp_doubleSeqParens` enable passing the sequence of tuples `(type, name)(type, name)` to `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH`, which would otherwise choke on it because of the commas.

Now it's just a matter of forming valid member declarations and print statements for each struct member:

```
#define DETAIL_DECLARE_FIELD(r, structName_, typeAndName_) \
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0, typeAndName_) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(1, typeAndName_);

#define DETAIL_PRINT_FIELD_1(structName_, type_, name_) \
    ::std::printf("  0x%04zx - " BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(type_) " " BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(name_) " = ", offsetof(structName_, name_)); \
    ::detail_printValue(obj_->name_);

#define DETAIL_PRINT_FIELD(r, structName_, typeAndName_) \
    DETAIL_PRINT_FIELD_1(structName_, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0, typeAndName_), BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(1, typeAndName_))
```

Choosing the appropriate format parameter for each value is a bit clunky. I've elected to defer that to an overload set that only prints the value and the newline, but you could also construct the format string on-the-fly and use a single `printf`.

```
void detail_printValue(float const &v) { std::printf("%f\n", v); }
void detail_printValue(int const &v)   { std::printf("%d\n", v); }
```

Voilà! [See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3740393a9e5fc44c)